# setting elements height based on the number of elements

Tags: html, css

here is my code

```
<style>
    .video-col { height: 50%}
</style>

<div   id="wrapper" style="height: 100vh ">
        <div class="video-col"  style="background: red"></div>
        <div class="video-col"  style="background: blue"></div>
</div>
```

i want my `.video-col` to cover the height of their wrapper , the problem is i can have up to 3  `video-col`  in the page in that case their height should be around 33%

is there anyway to do this with pure css without using js ?

basically i want

```
.video-col { height: 50%}
```

if there are 2 video-col in the page and

```
.video-col { height: 33%}
```

if there are 3 .video-col in the page

Comment: Any intro to flexbox will teach you how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Alohci, use flexbox.

```css
#wrapper {
    align-content: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}

.video-col {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="video-col" style="background: red"></div>
    <div class="video-col" style="background: blue"></div>
    <div class="video-col" style="background: orange"></div>
</div>
```

[See it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/2r4mfx0d/)

[css-trics dot com website](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) provide guide to flexbox that easy to understand, or maybe search for [css flex](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+flex) to learn more.